# Optimal coding in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

```
I have been asked which of the following methods is more optimal? 
I want to show the best-selling and latest products to users.In method A, I query the database twice.
In method B, I only query product models once, and in the template, I use filters to display the best-selling and newest. 
Is the second method more logical and better than the first method?
```

I have been asked which of the following methods is more optimal?
I want to show the best-selling and latest products to users.In method A, I query the database twice.
In method B, I only query product models once, and in the template, I use filters to display the best-selling and newest.
Is the second method more logical and better than the first method?

```
A : 
 def home(request):    
    create = Product.objects.all().order_by('-create')[:6]
    sell = Product.objects.all().order_by('-sell')[:6]
    return ...

B:
def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return ...

my template:
   for sell:
    {% for product in products|dictsortreversed:'sell'|slice:":8" %}
    --------------------
    for create : 
     {% for product in products|dictsortreversed:'create'|slice:":8" %}
```

Comment: Method A is more optimal.

Comment: why Method A is more optimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method A that you show in your question is more optimal. Consider that your model `Product` has *many* entries (let us say 1000 and be a little conservative, normally there would be many more) in the database.

Your method B is as follows:

```
def home(request):
    products = Product.objects.all()
    return ...

my template:
   for sell:
    {% for product in products|dictsortreversed:'sell'|slice:":8" %}
    --------------------
    for create : 
     {% for product in products|dictsortreversed:'create'|slice:":8" %}
```

What will this do? Well it will load *all* of the products in *memory* (This can cause a crash if there are too many products), sort them by their key in *python*.

Next your method A is like:

```
def home(request):    
    create = Product.objects.all().order_by('-create')[:6]
    sell = Product.objects.all().order_by('-sell')[:6]
    return ...
```

This is much more simpler, it will use an `ORDER BY` clause in your query and a `LIMIT` clause to get only the 6 results you need. Hence this is much more efficient on the memory. Next it is also much more *faster* considering that the sorting is done by the database which would likely have *indexes* on these columns to sort things faster.